# Is there a way to project and control a android screen on PC using USB connection

Tags: touchscreen

My android screen just recently broke and I can't use the touch. I would like to take some files off it but it is password protected and to access them I need to type in the password.

Comment: Take a look at questions under the broken screen tag: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you had USB debugging enabled, you are unlikely to be able to access your phone's screen over USB (as far as I know).

If you have an external keyboard, you could try plugging it in with a USB OTG cable and using that to type the password, or if you had USB debugging enabled you could try using [Vysor](http://vysor.io).